# How do you change date format in mysql?

Tags: mysql

How do you change date format from  `yy-mm-dd` to `day-month-year`?

I have tried this:

```
UPDATE stock
SET date_in = DATE(STR_TO_DATE(date_in, '%d/%m/%Y))
WHERE DATE(STR_TO_DATE(date_in, '%d/%m/%Y') <> '00-00-0000';
```

But it is giving me an error.

Comment: If you are storing your dates in columns of data type `datetime` or `date` (which you should be), they don't *have* a format.

Answer (score 3):

You store dates in database in one of the date formats (date,datetime,timestamp)
When you want to format them for view, either use your language, which surly has a date formatting functionality, or use the intrinsic mysql [date_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) in a SELECT statment